# Por qué hashmap sobrescribe valores

Tags: java, kotlin, hashmap

estoy haciendo un hashmap en Kotlin, el código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
  for (i in 1..semanas) {
        var dia = 7
        if (i == semanas) {
            if (dias != 0)  dia = dias 
        }
        for (j in 1..dia) {
            desayuno.clear()
            do {
                val t = listaComidas.random()
                if (t.tipo == "fruta") {
                    if (!desayuno.contains(t)) {
                        desayuno.add(t)
                    }
                }
            } while (desayuno.count() < 2)
            d["Desayuno"] = desayuno
            day[j.toString()] = d
        }
        sem[i.toString()]=day
    }
```

el problema que tengo es que cuando guardo

```
day[j.toString()] = d
```

coge el ultimo de 'd' y sobreescribe los anteriores.

el salida de código intercalada seria esta.

```
llave Desayuno , valor [Dieta(nombre=fruta2, tipo=fruta, calorias=52), Dieta(nombre=fruta3, tipo=fruta, calorias=12)]
llave 1 , valor {Desayuno=[Dieta(nombre=fruta2, tipo=fruta, calorias=52), Dieta(nombre=fruta3, tipo=fruta, calorias=12)]}
llave Desayuno , valor [Dieta(nombre=fruta3, tipo=fruta, calorias=12), Dieta(nombre=fruta2, tipo=fruta, calorias=52)]
llave 1 , valor {Desayuno=[Dieta(nombre=fruta3, tipo=fruta, calorias=12), Dieta(nombre=fruta2, tipo=fruta, calorias=52)]}
llave 2 , valor {Desayuno=[Dieta(nombre=fruta3, tipo=fruta, calorias=12), Dieta(nombre=fruta2, tipo=fruta, calorias=52)]}
llave Desayuno , valor [Dieta(nombre=fruta5, tipo=fruta, calorias=52), Dieta(nombre=fruta3, tipo=fruta, calorias=12)]
llave 1 , valor {Desayuno=[Dieta(nombre=fruta5, tipo=fruta, calorias=52), Dieta(nombre=fruta3, tipo=fruta, calorias=12)]}
llave 2 , valor {Desayuno=[Dieta(nombre=fruta5, tipo=fruta, calorias=52), Dieta(nombre=fruta3, tipo=fruta, calorias=12)]}
llave 3 , valor {Desayuno=[Dieta(nombre=fruta5, tipo=fruta, calorias=52), Dieta(nombre=fruta3, tipo=fruta, calorias=12)]}
llave Desayuno , valor [Dieta(nombre=Fruta1, tipo=fruta, calorias=32), Dieta(nombre=fruta4, tipo=fruta, calorias=22)]
llave 1 , valor {Desayuno=[Dieta(nombre=Fruta1, tipo=fruta, calorias=32), Dieta(nombre=fruta4, tipo=fruta, calorias=22)]}
llave 2 , valor {Desayuno=[Dieta(nombre=Fruta1, tipo=fruta, calorias=32), Dieta(nombre=fruta4, tipo=fruta, calorias=22)]}
llave 3 , valor {Desayuno=[Dieta(nombre=Fruta1, tipo=fruta, calorias=32), Dieta(nombre=fruta4, tipo=fruta, calorias=22)]}
llave 4 , valor {Desayuno=[Dieta(nombre=Fruta1, tipo=fruta, calorias=32), Dieta(nombre=fruta4, tipo=fruta, calorias=22)]}
```

como podeis ver el day coge el ultimo valor de d y sobrescribe los demás valores.

Comment: Tiene toda la pinta de que no creas un objeto nuevo, sino que modificas los valores del existente y lo vuelves a insertar, con lo que todos las inserciones en el Map son el mismo objeto.

Comment: Hola Pablo tengo una mutableList del objeto   `val listaComidas = mutableListOf<Dieta>(Dieta("Abadejo", "pescado", 128))`   son de mas objetos de los cuales hay 5 de frutas, por eso dentro del do{}while tengo  `val t = listaComidas.random()` y lo añado a desayuno, entiendo yo que añado un objeto aquí, nose si a eso te refieres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código está bien, sin embargo se ha de poner `d["desayuno"] = ArrayList<Dieta>(desayuno)` o eliminar el `desayuno.clear` y crear la variable ahí `val desayuno = mutableListOf<Dieta>()` se ve que hashmap trabaja con las referencias y por esté motivo no sirve el clear.

```
for (j in 1..dia) {
    val desayuno = mutableListOf<Dieta>()
    do {
        val t: Dieta = listaComidas.random()
        if (t.tipo == "fruta") if (!desayuno.contains(t)) {
            desayuno.add(t)
        }
    } while (desayuno.count() < 2)
    val d: MutableMap<String, Any?> = mutableMapOf() 
    d["desayuno"] = ArrayList<Dieta>(desayuno)// puede ser directamente desayuno
    day["$$j"] = d
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Examinemos los bucles anidados:

```
     for (j in 1..dia) {
        desayuno.clear()
        do {
            val t = listaComidas.random()
            if (t.tipo == "fruta") {
                if (!desayuno.contains(t)) {
                    desayuno.add(t)
                }
            }
        } while (desayuno.count() < 2)
        d["Desayuno"] = desayuno
        day[j.toString()] = d
    }
```

En cada iteración del bucle `for` vacías el objeto `desayuno` y le vuelves a añadir elementos, para luego insertar este objeto `desayuno` en el mapa `d`. Realmente, si omitimos el código del bucle do, lo verás más claro:

```
     for (j in 1..dia) {
        desayuno.clear() //vacío el objeto desayuno
           ... //código omitido // ... se añaden cosas al objeto
        d["Desayuno"] = desayuno // lo vuelvo a guardar, siempre con la misma clave
        day[j.toString()] = d //guardo en el día el mismo desayuno
    }
```

Realmente no sé para qué usas la variable `d`, pero reutilizar el las instancias en  `d` y en `desayuno` hace que lo que guardes en `day` siempre sea lo mismo... que acaba teniendo el valor de la última iteración.

Comment: Hola pablo, mi objetivo es este sin que se repita ningún valor, y que por cada comida tengan mínimo 2 o 3 objetos.
       semana 1
            dia 1 : desayuno[lista]
                    comida[lista]
                    cena[lista]
            dia 2 : desayuno[lista]
                    comida[lista]
                    cena[lista]